# Where put business logic on a Node+Express.js RESTApi

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, model-view-controller

I have the following Node+Express.js RESTApi architecture:

```
- controllers
- db
-- models
-- config
-- migrations
- helpers
- routes
- services
- test
package.json
index.js
```

Where is the right place to put the business rules? (controllers, models, services?)

Comment: I'm not really sure, but I have business logic split into models and controllers, mostly on models

Comment: there is only one place where you can put your business logic is controllers, because models is responsive to deal with DB communication, routers are used to define your route, and services are used for exchanging the information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what a see with your folder structures this is how I will make it. P.S This is how **I think** about your project structures just by reading the name of the folder, this is not perfect but can help you maybe.

```
- controllers -> logic before saving to the db, check permission, etc..
- db
-- models -> all the stuff who touch a models himself, the schema,etc
-- config -> config about the db, connection to the db etc
-- migrations -> all the migrations file for the db
- helpers -> helpers function like sum, total, pluralize, etc
- routes -> all the rest api route, where they take a controller as callback
- services -> stripe, aws s3 etc
- test -> all your test
package.json -> all your dependencies
index.js -> where everything start, your server instance etc
```

So you in your case the business logic go in controllers. Models can be use to add logic who touch the db value etc.

Comment: Thank you! Can you give me some examples of "Models logic who touch the db value etc."?

Comment: @EQuimper Thanks for the brief explaination. What comes under the migrations folder? You can give me a hint of what migration's like so that I can further google it down.

Comment: @DouglasMorais example hash the password of the user, compare the hash password with the one provided etc.

Comment: @AbhishekPathak if you use a sql database this is the migrations of your db. Example if you use Knex https://knexjs.org/#Migrations

Comment: @DouglasMorais a old boilerplate a build you can see the model logic here https://github.com/EQuimper/nodejs-api-boilerplate/blob/master/src/models/user.model.js

Comment: @AbhishekPathak, in my case I am using Sequelize.js. The Sequelize CLI auto generate this migration folder. This contains models (tables fields) definitions. I have other folder called "seeds" from Sequelize too. This contais all INSERTS. Combine migration + seeds for a complete database migration.

Comment: @AbhishekPathak you can checkout the full project on: https://github.com/douglasmoraisdev/node_movie_rental_api

Comment: DouglasMorais @EQuimper Thank you. I am still learning and it's great to know such tools exists. It is definitely going to come handy in the future.

Comment: i cant believe no one upvoted such a nice answer, what are you commenters even doing?

Answer (score 3):

A bit new to ExpressJS and the good thing is it's not as prescriptive as Rails and the usual PHP frameworks on how to organise code.

I am structing my code this way:

- route: as per previou comment: direct the API call to the right controller function
- controllers: receive the API calls with the req. data, do some validation in the context of the API call (http related, for example: API auth and so on)
- services: the controller then call a service that contains the business logic. The idea is the service (business logic) is not tied to a controller and to the req. data. The service receives the data it needs (from the extracted from the req. and maybe other things) and return other data that can be used by the controller for the res. data.

Comment: Aside from separation of concerns, the goal of separating business logic from all other components/directories/et al is to make it re-usable by the other components. If the business logic is in a controller, it is likely to only be re-usable by the single controller it lives in. Thus, having the business logic live in the 'services' directory achieves that.

Comment: That's neatly put @VincentBZ. How would go about naming files in services. Would each function have its own file or would you group similar functions under one file. For instance, functions that evaluate HTML page received from controller and return on page insight.

Comment: I've found a handy article that goes in more depth about what Matt has said. https://www.codementor.io/@evanbechtol/node-service-oriented-architecture-12vjt9zs9i

Comment: I have created a file that handles several “related” services.